# Create php function date to unix timestamp

Tags: php, function, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to create a php function that gets the current date and creates a unix timestamp for next day with time 00:00:00

Example:

Today = 03-09-2014
Tomorrow = 04-09-2014 00:00:00

I want to create the unix timestamp for Tomorrow (1409788800) but I want the function to do it for each day.

Anyone has done this before?

Comment: `strtotime('midnight tomorrow', $input_time)` works, unless you're thinking of something more complicated?

Comment: And $input_time should be current time?

Comment: You can leave it off entirely, if unspecified it uses the current time, I'd misread the question and thought you wanted to pass in a date.

Comment: plenty of dupes here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+timestamp+php. Please use search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Set to `+1 day`, then set the time manually.

```
date('d-m-Y 00:00:00', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

EDIT:

Misread, plus scragar's comment is more accurate.